# How do I erase the blackness around the world? (Blender 2d)

Tags: edit-mode

I cut around the world using a program. but when I add it to blender, the black frame still remains.[image]

Comment: If you are using eevee. make sure the material's _Blend Mode_ is set to something other than _Opaque_

Comment: thank you. my problem is solved